# script data table content into insert statements using one command

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have to create a script with an insert statement from one table in a database a few times a day.

It looks more or less like this:

Task -> Generate scripts -> choose table -> choose data only -> then choose file name and OK

Is there any way to automate this? I would like to have for example a bat file which does all the work and updates a file with the newest version of the database table.

Comment: would you be willing to use java to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to dump the data in the table to a text file periodically?  If so, what about using an SSIS package and scheduling it as a job.